# It is possible the underlying files have been updated. Spark

Tags: python, pyspark

I try to use spark to select some data from a list of 7z file. I used a "for loop". In each loop, I unzip the file and select some rows, put these rows in a dataframe by `df=df.union(rows)` and then use `rm` to delete the file because there's little space. When the loop ends, I use `toPandas()` to convert SparkDataframe to Pandas dataframe and put it in to excel.

then this error occurs:

```
stage 18.0 (TID 3399) (10.77.110.215 executor driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
File file:/home/Haruka/WEIBO/weibo_freshdata.2022-06-12 does not exist

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
```

Below are related code:

```
def search_weibo(sparksession, filename, keywords1, keywords2, keywords3):
    custom_schema = StructType([StructField("context", StringType())])
    try:
        f = sparksession.read.schema(custom_schema).format("text").load(filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Cannot load data from " + filename)
        return None
    expr = reduce(
        lambda x, y: x | y, [df["context"].contains(keyword) for keyword in keywords1]
    )
    df1 = df.filter(expr)
    df2 = df.filter(
        (df["context"].contains(keywords2[0])) & (df["context"].contains(keywords2[1]))
    )
    df3 = df.filter(df["context"].like("%" + keywords3[0] + "%" + keywords3[1] + "%"))

    dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
    df = reduce(lambda x, y: x.union(y), dfs)

    df_str = df.select(regexp_replace(df["context"], "^[\d]+\t", "").alias("dict_str"))
    keys_to_extract = [
        "is_retweet",
        "user_id",
        "nick_name",
        "weibo_id",
        "weibo_content",
        "zhuan",
        "ping",
        "zhan",
        "time_stamp",
        "r_user_id",
        "r_nick_name",
        "r_user_type",
        "r_weibo_id",
        "r_weibo_content",
        "d",
        "region_name",
    ]
    if not df_str.isEmpty():
        df_key_values = df_str.rdd.map(
            lambda row: extract_key_values(row, keys_to_extract)
        ).toDF(keys_to_extract)
        df_key_values = df_key_values.distinct()
        return df_key_values
    else:
        return None


def main():
    keywords1 = [...]
    keywords2 = [...]
    keywords3 = [...]
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("LargeFileReader").getOrCreate()
    errtime = []
    schema = StructType(
        [
            StructField("is_retweet", StringType()),
            StructField("user_id", StringType()),
            StructField("nick_name", StringType()),
            StructField("weibo_id", StringType()),
            StructField("weibo_content", StringType()),
            StructField("zhuan", IntegerType()),
            StructField("ping", IntegerType()),
            StructField("zhan", IntegerType()),
            StructField("time_stamp", TimestampType()),
            StructField("r_user_id", StringType()),
            StructField("r_nick_name", StringType()),
            StructField("r_user_type", StringType()),
            StructField("r_weibo_id", StringType()),
            StructField("r_weibo_content", StringType()),
            StructField("d", DateType()),
            StructField("region_name", StringType()),
        ]
    )
    accumulated_df = spark.createDataFrame([], schema=schema)
    for file in os.listdir("/home/data/Sources/WEIBO/"):
        print(file)
        if file[-2:] == "7z":
            err = os.system("7z x /home/data/Sources/WEIBO/" + file)
            if err:
                errtime.append(err)
                continue
            df = search_weibo(spark, file[:-3], keywords1, keywords2, keywords3)
            df.show()
            if not df.isEmpty():
                accumulated_df = accumulated_df.union(df)
            os.system("rm " + file[:-3])

    out = accumulated_df.toPandas()
    out.to_excel("~/ans/ans.xlsx", index=False)
```

Thank you all very much!

I saw some answers said that it was caused by read and write in the same path so I make a dir,and it doesn't work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

`accumulated_df` does not contains the data but only the path and schema of all the read files. When you do `accumulated_df.toPandas()`, it uses these information to read the files and transform the data to pandas. If, in the meantime, you deleted your files, then you receive the error message `It is possible the underlying files have been updated`. Just don't do that.

If your spark cluster is not big enough to have twice the amount of data you want to read with excel, it means either that your data are too small to be processed with Spark, or that they are too big to be processed in Excel.

---

If you insist in doing that, you have to save somewhere the data you need, then read them one more time to process them with pandas :

```py
for file in os.listdir("/home/data/Sources/WEIBO/"):
    print(file)
    if file[-2:] == "7z":
        err = os.system("7z x /home/data/Sources/WEIBO/" + file)
        if err:
            errtime.append(err)
            continue
        df = search_weibo(spark, file[:-3], keywords1, keywords2, keywords3)
        if not df.isEmpty():
            # line changed here 
            df.write.parquet("tmp", mode="append")
        os.system("rm " + file[:-3])

spark.read.parquet("tmp").toPandas().to_excel("~/ans/ans.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: I have lots of 7z file to read,and each file is about 50G,so I must delete the file

Comment: @JadeChen OK, so there is no way you can process that amount of data in Excel

Comment: In each file ,I picked about 100 rows of data so excel can do that.Should I try 5/10 times and then write it to excel,then rm the file?

Comment: @JadeChen I added a piece of code to change slightly the logic. If the final amount of data is small, then it should work with your case.